# Sharing Angular4 module

Tags: angular

I am newbie to Angular4 and need some helps
I am finding the way to make common Angular module for other to reuse like Angular Material for example

After the research, I have some questions as below

1. Should I publish to git or npm
2. Can current version of CLI 1.2.4 help on pack and publish
3. I found two library https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-npm-module-seed and https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library. Should I use them or there is another ways
4. What is the common ways you guys do on sharing component with team

Thanks for all you helps

Edit: I am using Angular CLI to create project

Answer (score 2):

If you gonna use the module inside the same project (aka same application) then it's easier to simply make it as a part of the application and import it in the root module.

Else, if you want to make a standalone module it's best to publish it to `npm` and use as a dependency. Then your team can reuse it in any project by simply adding it to `package.json`.

Here's a reference on how to create an angular 4 node module:
http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/

Answer (score 2):

I must say that you are thinking in right direction. The preferred method is to use generator-angular2-library and generate a skeleton. You may publish it to npm repo or your own private repo if your organization provides one.
Here is an article that should help you achieving this:
https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464